# How to set a value in controller indicating if a link exists on top partial part of its view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I have a view, that has a `prtial` for its header, that partial can have some links to for example going back to home page, going to profile page, etc...

Sometime some of those links can be hidden or disabled based on some situations.

What I need is in one of my controller action method I need to have accees to some sort of flag or variable that tell me if that home page button is on the page or not.  How can I do that ?

Comment: which action, the action which is rendering the page ?

Comment: Remember that actions execute before the view engine (and call it, in fact), so an action can never know what has or has not been rendered in a view.  All actions can do is pass data to a model, thus instructing the view how to render.  You need to figure out how to access the data that determines if the home page button gets rendered, rather than trying to read the results from an already rendered view.

Comment: @Jestin is right. You set how the View will be rendered. If you want to get back some information from the Client, manage the state of it.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller method you can have add a line like this in cases where you need to limit the links displayed:

```
ViewBag.LimitOptions = true;
```

Then in your partial view where you output your buttons, you can do this:

```
@if(ViewBag.LimitOptions != null)
{
  /*define links here*/
}
```